# Shortening the Object name inside the member method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

I'm writing a lot of JavaScript widgets and small apps using the Object Literal pattern.

One thing I do is inside one of the methods I will abbreviate the application name to "app."

I do this primarily because it's easier to write, and also I understand there is a small performance gain.

```
    var ApplicationName = {
       property : "foo",
       methodOne : function(){
          var app = ApplicationName;
          return app.property;
       },
       init: function(){
          var app = ApplicationName;
          app.methodOne();
       }
    }
ApplicationName.init();
```

Are there any issues with this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your approach, but it's not strictly necessary (and you can shorten it even further). Calling `init` like this:

```
ApplicationName.init()
```

...sets the value of `this` inside `init` to `ApplicationName`. Which allows you to do this:

```
var ApplicationName = {
    property : "foo",
    methodOne : function(){
        return this.property;
    },
    init: function(){
        return this.methodOne();
    }
}
```

Comment: I get hung up with the "this" keyword.  "This" refers to the object the function is being applied to, right?

Comment: The value of `this` inside a function is determined by how the function was called. Whenever you call a function as a method on an object, the value of `this` inside that function is the object the method was called on. More reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0):

No issues with your approach. I don't know if the following pattern might aid you too:

```
var ApplicationName = (function () {
    var app;
    return {
        property: "foo",
        methodOne: function() {
            return app.property;
        },
        init: function() {
            app = ApplicationName;
            app.methodOne();
        }
    }
})();

ApplicationName.init();

console.log(ApplicationName.property); // "foo"
```

This way you only have to alias `ApplicationName` once. It does mean that the `init()` method must be called first but I guess it is anyway :-)

Comment: @Raynos - how does this look like bad code? This is a very common pattern in JavaScript.

Comment: There is neglible performance difference between getting `app` and `ApplicationName`. Also setting `app = ApplicationName` in `init` feels rather ugly. I'd be better if it was `return (app = { ... })`

Answer (score 0):

There are no issues with this approach. In fact smaller javascript files are recommended, since they save server's and client's time and bandwidth. However, if you mind small files in your site, you'd better compress your javascript with one of the several tools available on the net rather than applying such small changes. If you have a good IDE with Ctrl+Space (i.e Autocomplete!) capability then it shouldn't be difficult to type them all. You can leave the compression to the compressor tool.

The gain in performance as you say might be as good as a few milliseconds, so usually people don't mind this too.

Overall, what you wrote is safe, but there are no significant changes in performance or file size so that one wants to prefer it or not.